# Multiple forms on page asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms, webforms

I have a problem with multiple forms on my asp.net website. On the Master page i have a small form for every page and on some pages i also want to have a form. I know it is not possible to have for form tags with runat=server, so i am searching for a solution.

Is it possible to deactivate the validators from one of the forms, so the other form can pass? Then i could manage the 2 forms together in the server-side c# code.

Is this possible or are there any other solutions u know?

Comment: Why are you using multiple form tags? why don't you have your `<form>` tags on the Master page and then define your content on the individual pages with Content and ContentPlaceHolder controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give your validation control a group name like

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="Login" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and use that group name to the button you want to validate on click like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" ValidationGroup="Login" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution for my problem! I put one form on the content and i used the validation groups to separate them.